# mamp pro virtual host will only work on port 8888

Tags: wordpress, port, virtualhost, mamp-pro

I have a series of vhosts that work fine on global settings of port 80 set in mamp pro. One new vhost I created will not work though on this port. I type in my vhost in thew browser or even use the link provded and it appends a :8888 onto the link and says can't establish connection to server.

When I change that vhost port # to 8888 then it works.

The problem is the :8888 remains and is screwing up my url routing for navigating the site especially with a standard wordpress build, I cant get into my admin section bc wordpress donest understand the :8888.

Any ideas how to fix this issue with mamp pro?

Comment: By default mamp adds the 8888 port. Change it to the 80 and 3306. But even after you change it, the 8888 has been saved to your Wordpress install url's so just go to your phpmyadmin and under wp_options table check that the home_url and site_url doesn't have the 8888 on them.

Comment: I already have the global settings in mamp set to 80 and 3306. I have many other vhosts using this that work fine. This new one doesn't unless I enter 8888 into the port number for that specific vhost on mamp. This issue remains with or without wordpress installed

Answer (score 3):

```
First you need to change port to 80 
Server->general Apache value to 80 then create vhost 
in Host ->add new 
Server name
ip/port you can add as * 
then disk location 
that it done !
```